# Mean number of edges in a hypercube graph in which random nodes are deleted

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory

I have the following problem. Suppose we have a hypercube of dimension L. Then the number of nodes is given by $2^L$ and the number of edges is given by $2^{L-1}*L$. Now each node is deleted with a probability given by $(1-p)$. The question is, what is the average number of edges for given $L$ and $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** For each edge, the probability that that edge is still there is $p^2$.

Now use additivity of expectations.

Comment: Well then it would be p^2*2^(L-1)*L, but that would undererstimate the mean number of edges. This is due to the effect that if two neighbouring nodes are deleted the number of edges decreases not as much as if they were no neighbours.

Comment: @HighwayJohn: That effect is taken care of by having $p^2$ instead of $1-2\cdot(1-p)$.

Comment: Hm, in the end I want to know the mean number of edges of each node. In my opinion this should be 2*(Mean number of edges)/(Mean number of nodes). If I use for the mean number of edges $e=  p^2*2^(L-1)*L$ as you suggest and for the mean number of nodes $n=2^L*p$ I get for the mean number of edges of each node $d=2e/n=p*L$. If I compare this to my numerics I notice that this equation overestimate d. So something must be wrong...

Comment: @HighwayJohn: If you want the expected number of edges incident to _a node known not to be deleted_, that can't be much else than $pL$, which is the expected number of its original neighbors that are still standing.  [However, dividing two expectations is not _in general_ a valid procedure for finding the expectation of the ratio].

Comment: Lets assume, that only a single edge survives. Then the probability $p$ for a random edge to exist is $p=1/2^L$. Hence we would get for the mean number of edges of each node $d=p*L=1/2^L*L\neq0$, according to your equation. But a single node has no edges. Hence something is wrong with this equation.

Comment: If p is very small usually there will be no edges at all, since existing nodes are probably no neighbours.

Comment: @HighwayJohn: I'm assuming you're choosing for each node whether or not to delete it _independently_ of all the other nodes. "Choose a single node and let it remain" is not the same as "Let each node remain with probability $|V|^{-1}$".

Comment: You mean it should make a difference, weather I say that a fixed number of $n$ edges will survive or the probability for a random edge to survive is $p=n/2^L$?

Comment: In my opinion in both cases, your result is only correct for large L.

Comment: @HighwayJohn: Not only _should_ it make a difference: It _does_ make a difference, as your example shows.

Comment: Hm, I am still not convinced. What would be the the value of d as a function of L and n?

Comment: Regarding my initial question you are of course right.

Answer (score 1):

One idea which doesn't provide an exact answer but gives a simple recursion is to solve for the base case, L=2. Let us say this is E(2,p). Then the L=3 case is two copies of the L=2 case with edges between corresponding vertices. The expected number of edges in the two copies of the L=2 case is simply twice the expected number of edges in the L=2 case, and then looking at the other 4 edges, they are indeed independent, and each has a probability of p^2, so the expected number of edges would be E(3,p) = 2*E(2,p)+$4p^2$. Then E(n+1,p) = 2*E(n,p) + $2^{n-1}p^2$. Not sure if this is right or even what you're looking for.